# Windows.old not gone after disk cleanup?

Tags: command-line, windows-10-preview, windows.old

I have tried using disk cleanup to remove 'previous versions of windows' but this only removes a few MB. The first time it went from around 5GB to around 900MB, then each time I run the disk cleanup it removes around 10MB. I've tried taking ownership using command prompt. While using the TAKEOWN command line, it says SUCCESS for each file but when I use RD or RMDIR, it says access denied for everything. I even run the DIR windows.old command line to check if the folders were not 'ghost folders' if that's a thing.

I am using Windows 10 Insider Build 10547 btw and somehow it also does not want to update. So, I reset it and that's why I got the windows.old folder again. Last time I updated my pc the folder was gone with a disk cleanup.

Comment: When it comes to the manual TakeOwn solution, you have to give yourself permission to delete it after you take ownership. Just because you own it doesn't automatically mean you have full rights assigned to it. :)

Between disk cleanup not removing it, and you saying the OS doesn't want to update, I'd suspect you have a larger problem, and I'm leaning towards bad disk/corrupt file-system as a first suspect to test.

Comment: Yes. That was what I was thinking, too. But I don't know if there is a command line to give myself permission to all these files and I don't want to go through each of them and do that manually. 
And the updates are good now after the reset.